# Excel 2007 VBA Code for list generating works but only sometimes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I'm putting together a list generator and I'm having trouble getting my code to work properly (again!).

### The code works for the first row of data but ignores all the others.

All the codes are the same, I've got 5 buttons. The Level # is stored in column X, so #24.

I want to be able to click the button and generate a list of the rows that contain the Level #, from the PI sheet to the Lists sheet.

The data that will be transferred is contact info and sizing info and is in the same row as the Level #.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'level 1 button
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
    With Worksheets("PI")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

'first row number where you need to paste values in Sheet1'
    With Worksheets("Lists")
    j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

For i = 1 To LastRow
   With Worksheets("PI")
       If .Cells(i, 24).Value = "1" Then
           .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Lists").Range("A" & j)
           j = j + 1
       End If
   End With
Next i
    End Sub

Private Sub Level5_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim i As Long, j As Long

   'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
   With Worksheets("PI")
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With

   'first row number where you need to paste values in Sheet1'
   With Worksheets("Lists")
      j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   End With

   For i = 1 To LastRow
       With Worksheets("PI")
           If .Cells(i, 24).Value = "5" Then
               .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Lists").Range("A" & j)
               j = j + 1
           End If
       End With
   Next i
    End Sub

Private Sub Lvl2_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim i As Long, j As Long

   'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
   With Worksheets("PI")
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With

   'first row number where you need to paste values in Sheet1'
   With Worksheets("Lists")
      j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   End With

   For i = 1 To LastRow
       With Worksheets("PI")
           If .Cells(i, 24).Value = "2" Then
               .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Lists").Range("A" & j)
               j = j + 1
           End If
       End With
   Next i
    End Sub

Private Sub Lvl3_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim i As Long, j As Long

   'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
   With Worksheets("PI")
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With

   'first row number where you need to paste values in Sheet1'
   With Worksheets("Lists")
      j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   End With

   For i = 1 To LastRow
       With Worksheets("PI")
           If .Cells(i, 24).Value = "3" Then
               .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Lists").Range("A" & j)
               j = j + 1
           End If
       End With
   Next i
End Sub

Private Sub Lvl4_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim i As Long, j As Long

   'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
   With Worksheets("PI")
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With

   'first row number where you need to paste values in Sheet1'
   With Worksheets("Lists")
      j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   End With

   For i = 1 To LastRow
       With Worksheets("PI")
           If .Cells(i, 24).Value = "4" Then
               .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Lists").Range("A" & j)
               j = j + 1
           End If
       End With
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of looping row by row, why not just use a filter?

Comment: I'm very new, I've got no idea how :( Pros/Cons?

Comment: The macro recorder is your friend.

Comment: Call one sub rather than repeat your code 5 times. What is the value of lastrow?

Comment: I want to be able to pick specifically Level 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 and not get the results from other ones. Would combining them under one SUB not mean they all get done? Lastrow is there to make sure it pastes below the last row used.

Comment: You can add a parameter to your sub. I meant what is its value when you step through the code?

Comment: hmm when I try to step through it gives me Subscript Out of Range just before getting to lastrow.